# How to figure out EMail was sent or not in C# window form application ?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

This is my Connection String, just fetching email id from Excel sheet and sending the mail.

```
  ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\Manish\\agent_mail_master.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
      SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
                            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("some@.com", "@password");
                            SmtpServer.Port = 2700;
                            SmtpServer.Host = "ac.maildirect.co.in";
                            mail.From = new MailAddress("some@example.com");
```

I need to check whether email is sent or not and need to display total successful mail sent with email id's.

Comment: There is no easy way to check whether an email was sent. The best you can do is just a try-catch because the receiving individual would need to signal a response back to accurately know if the email was sent properly.

Comment: thanks @Ckrempp i did same way as you said.